# How to convert a string (X hours X minutes X seconds) to datetime in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a column that stores time as such, '3 hours 10 minutes'. I want to sum the column to get a total amount of hours. How can I convert this string into a timestamp?

Comment: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-python Check out this website - it answers your questions!

Comment: to convert it to a timestamp, you need some start timestamp atleast.

Comment: A datetime.datetime instance refers to a specific date with a specific time and optionally a timezone. It looks like you only have a specific time. Do you have a date that these times occur on? If you do not want to use a datetime.datetime representation, what kind of timestamp are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

To parse string into `datetime`, you can use `datetime.strptime()`:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> 
>>> datetime.strptime('3 hours 10 minutes', '%H hours %M minutes')
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 3, 10)
```

This will return a `datetime` object, which you can process further.

More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).